# Build an multi step form with ngb-tabset and selectors

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular2-directives, angular-reactive-forms

I have  a big form with steps, i was implementing all inputs in the same html file, then i tried to build a forms controls with the steps. My html file looks like this before

```
<ngb-tabset #t="ngbTabset">
    <ngb-tab title="Fase 1 " id="fase1">
       <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            stuff..
       </ng-template> 
    </ngb-tab>

    <ngb-tab title="Fase 2 " id="fase2">
       <ng-template ngbTabContent>
             stuff..
     </ng-template> 
    </ngb-tab>    
</ngb-tabset>
```

And my `formGroup` was in this way

```
initResourceForm() {
    this.resourceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [0],
        inputStuff: [''],
        ...
        })
}
```

Then i created components for each form step in order to use selector and shorten the html file. Because of this i divided the `formGroup` in steps and now look like this,

```
initResourceForm() {
    this.resourceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [0],
        fase1: this.formBuilder.group({
            stuffFase1: [''],
            ...
        }),
        fase2: this.formBuilder.group({
            stuffFase1: [''],
            ...
        }),
    })
}
```

And my html file looks like

```
<ngb-tabset #t="ngbTabset">
    <app-fase1></app-fase1>
    <app-fase2></app-fase2>
</ngb-tabset>
```

And the html file of each fase has a `<ngb-tab>` and look likes

```
<ngb-tab title="Fase 1 " id="fase1">
  <ng-template ngbTabContent>
    <form [formGroup]="resourceForm.controls.fase1">
     stuff...

    <p>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="t.select('fase2');">Next</button>
    </p>

  </ng-template> 
</ngb-tab>
```

I didnt nothing special in Fases components, and any component is rendered in the main Form Component

In order to clarify my question the tree folder is this way

```
main-form/
  fase1-form/
     fase1.component.html
     fase1.component.ts
     fase1.component.spec.ts
     fase1.component.css
  main-form.component.html
  main-form.component.ts
  main-form.component.spec.ts
  main-form.component.css
```

Comment: Hey Did you find any solution ?